# insert data into access database using c# not working

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, insert

I am trying to add data into an access database, so far this is what I have.

```
  try
        {
            connection.Open();

            String dataInsert = "INSERT into ClientsT (FirstName, LastName, Address, Email, Phone, CellPhone, Notes) values('" + boxAddName.Text.ToString() + "', '" + boxAddLastName.Text + "', '" + boxAddAdress.Text + "', '" + boxAddEmail.Text + "', '" + boxAddPhone + "', '" + boxAddCellPhone + "','" + boxAddObs.Text + "')";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(dataInsert, connection);


            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Client added,");
        } catch(Exception ex){
            MessageBox.Show("Error :" + ex);
        }

    }
```

It does't give me any king of error menssage, the code executes just fine but nothing is added to the database.

Please note that I am farly new to c# and it's my first time working with databases.

Comment: You are to never do code like this. You **must** use parameters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/JJ943772.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now hang on a minute there!

You are introducing a potentially disastrous security hole. Let me show you why:

```
String dataInsert = "INSERT into ClientsT (FirstName, LastName, Address, Email, Phone, CellPhone, Notes) values('" + boxAddName.Text.ToString() + "', '" + boxAddLastName.Text + "', '" + boxAddAdress.Text + "', '" + boxAddEmail.Text + "', '" + boxAddPhone + "', '" + boxAddCellPhone + "','" + boxAddObs.Text + "')";
```

In particular these lines:

```
boxAddName.Text.ToString() // You're converting a string to a string, which is redundant. :P You are also missing a semicolon here.
boxAddLastName.Text
boxAddAdress.Text
boxAddEmail.Text
boxAddPhone // Not a security problem, but you're inserting the TextBox control, not it's text.
boxAddCellPhone // Same as above.
boxAddObs.Text
```

What you're doing with this is basically allowing the user to put *anything* they want into the database. With this, the user can insert whatever they want, or even use an `SQL injection` exploit. You should always sanitize your input.

You could do something like this:

```
    string Query = "INSERT into ClientsT (FirstName, LastName, Address, Email, Phone, CellPhone, Notes) values(@FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @Email, @Phone, @CellPhone, @Notes)";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query))
    {
        connection.Open();

        // Please make sure you edit the SqlDbType to the correct SQL Data Type. They are VarChar by default in this example. It's on you to fix that.
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar) = boxAddName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar) = boxAddLastName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar) = boxAddAddress.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar) = boxAddEmail.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar) = boxAddPhone.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CellPhone", SqlDbType.VarChar) boxAddCellPhone.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Notes", SqlDbType.VarChar) = boxAddNotes.Text;

        // Insert writing code here.
    }
```

Your problem is simply this:

You're trying to insert the `TextBox` *control* on multiple occasions. Look at `boxAddPhone`, and `boxAddCellphone`: you need to use `TextBoxName.Text`, not `TextBoxName`. So it's going to throw an exception, and since you're catching ALL exceptions, you won't know what went wrong. It could be anything.

Finally, you're also adding `boxAddObs`, which is *not* inserted with the first `INSERT INTO ClientsT (...)` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the help it works now, and as it seems that i got it to work before , the problem is that I didn't know that visual studio creates a copy of the database and puts it into the folder "bin", when I got there and check the database e saw all my testes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'boxAddPhone' & 'boxAddCellPhone' are missing ".Text"